# Why is the JSON bool data pass to the Django backend as a string?

Tags: python, json, django, request

The butt joint of `JSON data` and Python `request.params`:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/physicalservertask/list_for_home_workpanel/?has_physicalserver=false
```

As you can see, I add the `has_physicalserver` param in the `url`, which should be logical 'true', logical 'false', but in my Django API I get it as a `str`.

```
has_physicalserver_list = query_params.pop('has_physicalserver')
has_physicalserver = has_physicalserver_list[0] if (isinstance(has_physicalserver_list, list) and len(has_physicalserver_list) > 0) else ''
```

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: Because it's not JSON, it's just a query parameter. The values are always strings; if you want to parse it, you should do so explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query parameter are strings. You can parse it using `json`.

```
import json
has_physicalserver_list = query_params.pop('has_physicalserver') # string true/false
has_physicalserver_list = json.loads(has_physicalserver_list) # True/False
```